# Criando uma VIEW de uma VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com seguinte problema na empresa, onde que tenho vários painéis que obtém informações de uma VIEW que não possui NOLOCK na query.

Para não ter que mudar cada painel, seria possível eu criar uma view,e dessa view recriar usando o STATEMENT WITH(NOLOCK)?

Exemplo:

View Padrão:

```
estoque_resumo_diario
```

Criaria uma outra view puxando dessa:

```
 CREATE VIEW estoque_resumo_diario_nolock AS SELECT * FROM estoque_resumo_diario
```

E refaria a original como sendo:

```
ALTER VIEW estoque_resumo_diario as SELECT * FROM estoque_resumo_diario_nolock WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Ou é melhor eu refazer a view inteira utilizando NOLOCK nas interações entre as tabelas, não tenho o problema de trazer "Lixo" devido a trazer dados que não foram commitados.

Comment: Qual o motivo de utilizar NOLOCK?

Comment: Existem muitas transações simultâneas nas tabelas que se incluem nessa view em questão, deadlocks são constantes, e como não posso mudar a estrutura do banco, estou de mãos atadas, a maioria das tabelas utilizam clustered index.